# ¿Cuál es la palabra más generalmente aceptada para decir "calzado deportivo"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, deportes, ropa

Desde hace mucho tiempo he tenido esta duda, pero recientemente en esta pregunta [nuevos zapatos por/para España?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3571/nuevos-zapatos-por-para-espana/3573#3573) me surgió nuevamente.

Yo siempre creí que la palabra "zapatilla" era la más generalmente aceptada para decir calzado deportivo. Que fuera a donde fuera si dijera "zapatillas" la gente me iba a entender.
Pero como pueden ver en algunos comentarios del [post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3571/nuevos-zapatos-por-para-espana/3573#3573), no es el caso.

Si bien [*tenis*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZTQHXFp) en el DLE, pareciera encajar perfectamente con lo que pido (*3. m. pl. zapatillas de deporte*), no es el caso. Porque no creo que las personas entiendan que uno se está refiriendo a "calzado deportivo" cuando dice "tenis" en la mayoría de los países (conozco varios).

Además quisiera una palabra oficial del idioma castellano, y no jerga, por ejemplo pareciera que en Uruguay le dicen "champions", pero eso me suena que es la marca de calzado deportivo que se hizo famoso.

Comment: In today's American English, if you call a pair of walking shoes "a pair of sneakers" you are marking yourself as being a golden ager.

Comment: Una pregunta: las botas de senderismo también serían un tipo de calzado deportivo, ¿no piensas? Por eso me gusta la idea de usar otra palabra.

Comment: @zx81 no son del mismo tipo de deporte al que me refiero, pero es verdad no lo habia pensado.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es una pregunta difícil en mi opinión dado que varía bastante de país a país dependiendo de la cultura.

Por ejemplo en Estados Unidos he escuchado muchos hispanos decirle "snickers", pero eso debe venir del inglés *Sneakers*.

También depende del deporte, por ejemplo en el caso de Colombia, tenis es para casi todos los deportes excepto golf y fútbol donde se les llama *Guayos*.

Ahora bien, en mi opinión la palabra más adecuada para que se reconozca en la mayoría de países simplemente no existe. Para que todos te entiendan puedes decir simplemente **zapatos deportivos**. Fin de la historia. Te aseguro que aunque en algunos países te mirarán raro, todos te entenderán y es la forma más correcta de "alto español" que puedes utilizar.

Si no, puedes utilizar una de estas, pero teniendo en cuenta el país donde estás:

- tenis
- zapatillas
- playeras
- deportivos
- championes
- kets
- zapas
- snickers

Como se dijo también, para que sea más claro se podría decir *zapatillas deportivas*, dado que en varios países zapatillas no son exclusivamente para el deporte sino para otras actividades como el ballet.

Comment: En México la más común es `tenis`.

Comment: @Roflo. En Cuba tambien

Comment: En Chile se dice siempre 'zapatilla'. No hay necesidad del modificador 'deportiva'.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>Se añade esta referencia de acuerdo con lo indicado en [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674). Edita libremente para incluir la versión de tu país o región.</sub>

Los invito a mejorar y corregir libremente este resumen:

## Uso general:

- calzado deportivo
- zapatillas deportivas

## Argentina

- botines
- zapatillas

## Chile

- zapatillas

## Colombia

- tenis
- guayos (golf y fútbol)

## Costa Rica

- tenis
- tacos (fútbol)

## Cuba

- tenis
- tacos (fútbol)

## Ecuador

- zapatos de caucho

## España

- zapatillas / zapatillas deportivas
- bambas
- botas (baloncesto y fútbol)
- deportivas
- playeros
- playeras
- tenis

## Estados Unidos

- snickers

## México

- tenis
- taquetes (fútbol, béisbol)

## Perú

- zapatillas

## Uruguay

- championes o champion

## Venezuela

- zapatos de goma

Comment: En Perú se le dicen **zapatillas** a cualquier calzado deportivo.

Comment: En Chile, "zapatos de fútbol" y el resto "zapatillas"

Comment: En Ecuador decimos zapatos de caucho y en Estados Unidos dicen sneakers.

Answer (score 2):

*Deportivas* es probablemente la palabra más utilizada. Aunque supongo que dependerá de la demografía.

Yo he oido también *playeros* en la misma forma que los típicos *tenis*. Aunque no sé si eso es jerga o está admitido en todas las zonas hispanoparlantes.

Curiosamente al calzado de futbol (y a veces otros deportes como baloncesto) lo llaman *botas* (como en "¡Las botas de futbol son muy caras!").

Comment: En argentina le dicen botines al calzado de futbol. Deportivas, nunca lo oí en mi vida :S
Tenis segun la rae es calzado deportivo además del deporte. Y Playeras es un tipo de zapatilla según la RAE también

Comment: @Dzyann. Me parece que en Cuba le decimos "tacos" a los zapatos de jugar futbol.

Comment: Al menos en mi zona (Asturias, Espana) `playerOs` es la ùnica comùn y aceptada. Tanto `tenis` (es un deporte), `zapatillas` (son las de estar en casa), el mismo `playeras` en femenino, `deportivas`... nos suenan (o al menos a mì) ajenas.

Es ciertamente un tema difìcil. Como recomiendan por arriba, si quieres un nombre global usa `calzado deportivo` que es, por ejemplo, la soluciòn que toman los grandes almacenes.

Comment: ¡Gracias! Pensaba que nadie más la ibna a decir jaja. La gente es vaga para hablar, no dicen "zapatillas deportivas", dicen simplemente "deportivas".

Answer (score 2):

Según la RAE es correcto usar Tenis para referirse al calzado deportivo.

> [**tenis.**](http://dle.rae.es/tenis)
>
> (Del ingl. lawn-tennis).
>
> 1. m. Juego practicado por dos personas o dos parejas, que se lanzan alternativamente una pelota, utilizando raquetas, por encima de una
>      red, con el propósito de que la otra parte no acierte a devolverla.
> 2. m. Instalaciones de un club de tenis.
> 3. **m. pl. Calzado de tipo deportivo.**

Comment: Como dije en mi pregunta tenis no encaja con lo que pido, porque en muchos paises no se usa así y no te entenderían si dices "tenis", solo pensarían del deporte.

Comment: Si lo que buscas es una palabra que se pueda entender en todo tipo de situación y en cualquier país hispanohablante, te deseo mucha suerte.

Comment: Incluso por ejemplo en España tenis se usa solo en ciertas regiones. Lo he oído en el Galicia, por ejemplo, pero en Madrid suena raro.

Comment: Soy gallego y en efecto tenis es el único término que se usa aquí

Answer (score 2):

En Uruguay se dice *championes* (plural) o *champion* (singular) a cualquier tipo de zapatillas deportivas. Se les dice comúnmente así por todos los uruguayos. Cuando alguien dice *zapatillas* se refiere en general a un tipo de calzado deportivo tipo "nautico", o de mucama, más simple y básico.
En Argentina se le llama *zapatilla* a todos los tipos de calzado deportivo.

Answer (score 1):

Soy costarricense, he viajado a varios países de Latinoamérica, conozco gente de Argentina, Brasil, Guatemala, Perú, Colombia y casi de todo el resto de países latinos y te aseguro que incluso en Brasil, que lo que hablan es portugués, te entenderían al decir **calzado deportivo**.  Ya es una cosa muy aislada –la cual nunca he visto– que algún latino no entienda eso. Es casi inherente de cualquier persona que hable castellano entender ese término. Que se usen otros términos es totalmente cierto pero, si logras encontrar algo mas estándar que **calzado deportivo**, entonces me cuentas porque para mí sería un gran descubrimiento.

En Costa Rica también tendemos a decirle *tenis* a todo lo que sea estilo deportivo. Por ejemplo, si entras a una tienda skate se sobreentiende que vas buscando unas CIRCA , DVS, DC, GLOBE, ES, VESTAL y etc. etc. Si entras a una tienda de deporte al aire libre se sobreentiende que andas buscando unas TIMBERLAND , MERREL, HI-TECH, COLUMBIA y etc. etc. Si entras a una tienda de deporte estilo atletismo, a las cuales acá las llamamos *tiendas deportivas*, se sobreentiende que buscas unas NIKE, REBOOK, FILA, PUMA, UMBRO, etc. Ahora, si entras a una tienda que no parece ser de un solo concepto sino que venden de todo, al decirle al vendedor que buscas calzado deportivo el vendedor entiende inmediatamente que buscas zapatos para salir a correr, a caminar, para practicar fútbol sala, basketball, etc.

Lo único muy de nosotros es que a los zapatos que usan los futbolistas como del Real Madrid y el Arsenal y demás futbolistas profesionales siempre y siempre les llamamos *tacos*, por lo de los taquillos que tienen por debajo.

Answer (score 0):

En España se ha utilizado siempre "zapatillas de deporte", siendo la precisión importante, al menos en algún contexto, para diferenciarlos de las zapatillas para estar en casa. También se usaba  "zapatillas deportivas" que ha derivado en el simple adjetivo sustantivado de "deportivas", forma abreviada, que aunque reconocida en el diccionario de la RAE, puede prestarse a alguna confusión (no deja de ser un adjetivo que se puede aplicar a otras cosas que no sean zapatillas) y parece más apropiada para un uso coloquial que para situaciones más formales.

Por supuesto, también se han usado en España muchos nombres comerciales como genéricos que se aplican a cualquier marca, pero yo huiría de esas expresiones como de la peste. Cambian muy deprisa en el tiempo y en el espacio. Hoy son la "snikers" por EEUU, las "naic" (Nike) por España, como ayer fueron las "bambas" (Wamba) o las "gorila" muchísimo antes (que siguen existiendo, pero sin la fama que tenían en los años 70) ¿Y mañana? Son palabras con fecha de caducidad que es mejor dejarlas en el congelador.

Respecto a las botas de fútbol, aunque es término no parece muy apropiado ya que no cubren la pierna, el uso es comprensible porque las zapatillas en general son calzados de comodidad, flexibles  (que es lo que necesitan la mayoría de los deportistas), y las botas es un calzado más duro, cuya función principal es la protección (que es lo que necesitan los futbolistas en particular) y ya de paso, romperle el menisco a la estrella del equipo rival con los enormes tacos de su suela, que no tienen otro tipo de zapatillas deportivas.

Comment: Lo que me molesta un poco es que pareciera que las palabras en la RAE que definen lo que yo quiero se usan solo en algunos países. Es interesante ver como algo tan común podría causar problemas de comunicación. ¿Cúales son las zapatillas de estar en casa? Son las "pantuflas"?

Comment: @Dzyann. No necesariamente. Las pantuflas y las babuchas no tienen talón (Más que zapatillas para andar por casa, son zapatillas para matarse rodando por las escaleras). Hay también hay zapatillas caseras que son un calzado completo (y más seguro).

Comment: entonces no se cuales son las zapatillas de andar en casa :D

Comment: Pies las pantuflas y [lo que no son pantuflas](http://zapatoshombre.com.es/files/2010/12/Zapatillas-cl%C3%A1sicas.jpeg), pero que no te podrías para andar por la calle.

Comment: @Dzyann: respecto de tu primer comentario: en español es inevitable encontrarse con diferencias regionales en vocabulario, y mientras más común un concepto, por lo general mayor el grado de diferenciación de las palabras dependiendo del lugar. El aporte de los idiomas nativos que hay/hubo en cada región es mucho más grande de lo que se cree, al menos en lo referido al vocabulario.

Comment: @Nicolás es verdad lo que decis, pero normalmente la palabra "oficial" suele ser conocida en todas las zonas aunque quizás no usada. En este caso es no se cumple. Es muy interesante.

Comment: Quería decir "Pues" en el anterior comentario. O la tecla "U" está demasiado cerca de la "I", o habrá sido un lapsus por hablar de calzado.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la respuesta está en tu misma pregunta: "Calzado deportivo". De esta manera todos hemos entendido a qué te referías de manera inmediata.

En México el término común es tenis, pero tienes razón, no en todos los países de habla hispana entenderían ese término y si a nosotros en México nos preguntas por zapatillas te mandaremos a la sección de calzado para dama y observarás zapatos con tacón.

Para que toda Hispanoamérica entienda no se puede utilizar solamente una palabra, tendrás que usar más de una: **calzado deportivo** o **zapatos deportivos**.

Comment: ¡Bienvenida, Kenia! Te edité un poco la respuesta, especialmente para indicar que en lugar de Latinoamérica usamos Hispanoamérica para allí donde se habla castellano. Esperamos leerte muchas buenas respuestas :)